# Show specific content on parent custom post type and all children

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

I have 5 main posts within a custom post type. Some of these posts will have children. I have content that should only be displayed on the parent post and all children of that post. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a condition based on post ID:

```
<?php if (is_page(12) || $post->post_parent=="12") { ?>

    <ul>
        Your Menu
    </ul>

<?php } else { ?>

    <ul>
        Another Menu (or put nothing here)
    </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

If you don't know how to locate the post ID:

"Roll over any page, post or category with your cursor (while logged in and in the "manage" area of course), and the page, post or cat_id number appears in the progress bar in the bottom of the browser." - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-is-the-post-id-number

Comment: Thanks! It's showing the content on the child pages but not the parent. How do I show it on the parent as well? Thanks for your help.

Comment: the if(is_page(Your-post-ID) should be doing that. Did you include that portion?

Comment: I ended up changing is_page to is_single and that did the trick. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Oh, yes! My bad. So glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear...I think what you're trying to ask is how to display the parent content for that post...and then also the content for each child?

Try this:

FOR THE PARENT (let's say your content is the title)

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?> 

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

FOR THE CHILDREN

```
<?php

    global $post;
    $child_pages_query_args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'your-custom-type',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'orderby'     => 'menu_order'
    );

    $child_pages = new WP_Query( $child_pages_query_args );

    if ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : while ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : $child_pages->the_post();
?>      

        <div>SOME CHILD CONTENT</div>
```

END CHILDREN

```
<?php 

        endwhile; endif;

        wp_reset_postdata(); 

?>
```

END PARENT

```
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

The whole thing together will look like this:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?> 

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php

    global $post;
    $child_pages_query_args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'your-custom-type',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'orderby'     => 'menu_order'
    );

    $child_pages = new WP_Query( $child_pages_query_args );

    if ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : while ( $child_pages->have_posts() ) : $child_pages->the_post();
        ?>                              

            <div>SOME CHILD CONTENT</div>           

    <?php 

    endwhile; endif;

    wp_reset_postdata(); 

    ?>


    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry it was unclear. If I have a custom post type named Markets and under Markets are 5 posts (auto, aerospace, marine, rail, energy). if, say, Rail, needs a menu in the sidebar on the parent and all children then I am looking for a conditional statement that will show the menu only on those specific pages. I am using one template file named "single-market.php". Is that clearer?

Comment: So when you say your posts "auto", "aerospace" etc. Is "auto" just the title of that post?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.